# Bottom navigation item menu custom background

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to add a background as shown in the image, to the menu item in the android bottom navigation.

[image: Bottom Navigation]

I have used the following selector as item background (selector_bottom_nav.xml)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  android:top="-6dp" android:left="-6dp" android:right="-6dp" android:drawable="@color/blue_light" android:state_checked="true">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/blue_light"/>
    <size android:width="2dp" android:height="6dp"/>
</shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@color/blue"/>
</selector>
```

And included in the bottom navigation like

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/selector_bottom_nav"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

But I end up getting like this.

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?